# Le plus-que-parfait and surcomposé.

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

Someone told me that *Le plus-que-parfait* is the same as *past surcomposé*. For instance: 
J'ai eu fini = J'avais fini
 Is that true?
 What's the difference between those two?